# How the grpc Client implementation manage more request at the same time?

Tags: go, grpc

I'm using `grpc` as `IPC` in a new software that I'm building but I came across this question: the grpc Client implantation in Go is synchronous or asynchronous?
Surfing on internet I discover that the C++ has both implementation but in Go there is lack of documentation about this feature (apart an issue on GitHub).
For this reason I start inspecting the Client code and I found that the client request is made by the `invoke` function ([here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/9b791e0ea399a912e17e176e5de6e7ac7d8c15ff/call.go#L150) the code) and seems that is running synchronously. 
For this reason I'm supposing that instead of using a global client and then pass to the struct that use the grpc functions I should create a client for each request to prevent a synchronous behaviour.
e.g.
Instead of:

```
type Foo struct {
    ClientA *grpc.Client
}
type Bar struct {
    ClientB *grpc.Client
}
//Other stuff
client := createNewClient() //This function return a *grpc client 
foo := Foo{client}
bar := Bar{client}
```

I should create a new client for each function of `Foo` and `Bar` struct for executing calls not thread blocking. Is it correct?

Comment: Go doesn't really have threads, you can open thousands of goroutines at once easily, the whole scheduling model of go make the concept of async programming redundant. So just don't worry and open as many threads as you cant. the server probably already does that per connection already.

Comment: I'm not worry about open thousands of new grouting (the go routine stack is very light, about 2kb) but more on how much will cost each client spawn. Anyway I'll implement and at least I'll make a pull request on grpc repository

Comment: What is grpc.Client? I don't see anything like that in the API? https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc Do you mean ClientConn? If so I don't understand why you can just invoke grpc call in separate goroutine. Do you have any specific constrains?